# Sending a value from server to client with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using the following projects in order to create an asynchronous communication between [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx) sockets. When I am running those projects I am sending a message from the client to the server thus I got the message:

> Data : recording EOF, Sent 14 bytes to client.

What I want to achieve is to send a boolean variable from the server to the client with the sockets. Is it doable to do so, I am wondering since in the code I have the server which waiting and listens and the client which sends data, can I do the opposite? In general what I want is to send a boolean to several clients. Why am I need the End of File in order to send a string? Is it necessary to convert everything to string?

**EDIT**: In general what I want is to send a variable from one computer to two others in order a process to begin simultaneously in all computers. In fact to create a switcher that gives a signal to begin a process in 2-3 machines in the same time.

I tried to use the following code for **server**:

```
class Program
{
    const int PORT_NO = 2201;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
        IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        listener.Start();
        //---incoming client connected---
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        //---read incoming stream---
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        //---convert the data received into a string---
        string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);
        //---write back the text to the client---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + dataReceived);
        nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        client.Close();
        listener.Stop();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and for **client**:

```
class Program
{
    const int PORT_NO = 2201;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //---data to send to the server---
        string textToSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);
        //---send the text---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        //---read back the text---
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
        Console.ReadLine();
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Just in the case I am working in the same machine. I will have in total 4 machines and I want the one of them to give a singal to the rest of them to begin recording rgb stream. Thus the server should send signal to the clients to begin recording. What should I do to change the behavior of the server to send data and not listen. Is it possible to have several machines listening and waiting for a signal to be given?

**EDIT:**

```
private void mouseClick1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => StartServer());
        thread.Start();

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;

            try
            {
                obj = new Capturer();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e1.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void mouseClick2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            obj.flag2 = true;
        }
    }
```

My code as it is now with left click calls startServer() function with a new thread which is the main code in @Ians implementation and afterthat I call my object. When I click right click I change a flag and the capturer stops. How can I stop also the server or pause in order to open it again with the left click?

Comment: to my knowledge, you can but the method I do not know, have a look at this. p.s. what I can recall is convert the data you want to send to a byte[] - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2477/Multi-threaded-Client-Server-Socket-Class

Comment: apologies, just realized that this is in c++, just search codeproject's website for a client server network transfer for c#, I have used one from this website, hope this helps

Comment: @Ian thanks for your super analytical answer. I am going to try all your steps. :P

Comment: @JoseRamon great! :D Just note that the last step (step 9 in server and (step 7 in client) is for you to change. That's why the code I gave is quite different from those steps. However, the code I gave was a working version without you need to change anything. The idea for this code is to share with you how Async can be defined and will be working. Then you only need to change the last step to adapt it to your need. =)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Answers to the questions first:

> Q: Is it necessary to convert everything to string?...In general what I
>   want is to send a variable from one computer to two others in order a
>   process to begin simultaneously in all computers.
>
> A: No, it is not necessary to convert everything to string when sending
>   using `Socket`. You may send `byte[]` which you most probably want.
>
> Q: What I want to achieve is to send a boolean variable from the server
>   to the client with the sockets
>
> A: Do you mean `boolean` or `byte`? Because the basic variable type which you 
>   will get from the `Socket` is `byte`. You could always change `byte`
>   to `bool` from the sender/receiver side by doing like
>
> `bool val = byteToCheck > 0;`
>
> A2: And since your server is `Console` Application, I recommend to take
>   a look on hex `string` to `byte[]` conversion. This way, you could
>   write something in `string` but interprets it as `byte[]`. Check
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa). The whole idea here is pretty simple. That is: you type in
>   `string`, but it will be sent as `byte[]`. And since it is `byte[]`
>   you can have any value in it.

And here I present my solution to handle your (1) multiple clients, (2) `Async` connect & accept & receive, but having (3) send sync, as well as (4) conversion from `hex string` to `byte[]` (the structure & idea), and last but not least (5) working code with user input (for you to change this part) for testing!

I would solve such problem using simple `Socket` class, since it is the solution I am most familiar with. But you could always do similarly if you use your `TcpListener.Server` (which is the underlying network of `Socket` class). And, as you desire, I would do that with `ASync`.

There are several steps needed to achieve what you want in both your server and your client:

---

**Server**

1. Make your `Socket` as class field rather than method field, since you will use if everywhere and you need multiple methods to achieve what you want. And initialize it as soon as you started your main routine.

   ```
   const int PORT_NO = 2201;
   const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
   static Socket serverSocket; //put here as static
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
       Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
       serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
       serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
       //your next main routine
   }
   ```
2. Since the server will serve many clients, I will recommend you to use `ASync` rather than `Sync` for the process. Initialize your `Socket` by using `BeginAccept` rather than using `Accept`, put  `acceptCallback` in your `BeginAccept`

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
       Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
       serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
       serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
       serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);      
       //other stuffs
   }
   ```
3. Define `acceptCallback`, which is where you will go when you accept a `Socket`. Put `EndAccept` there.

   ```
   private void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult result) { //if the buffer is old, then there might already be something there...
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = null;
       try {
           socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(result); // To get your client socket
           //do something later
       } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...        
           //do something later
       }
   }
   ```
4. I would typically list my client sockets, and do something on client disposal (that is unlisted it) - but this depends on the need. In this case, you seem to need it. And don't forget to create buffers, etc... This is for buffering the incoming data.
5. Start to accept something received from the client, using another `ASync` `BeginReceive` on the client `Socket` (and now you need `receiveCallback`). Then, **very important**, repeat your `BeginAccept` to accept other clients!

   ```
   private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
   private static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //buffer size is limited to BUFFER_SIZE per message
   private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>(); //may be needed by you
   private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult result) { //if the buffer is old, then there might already be something there...
       Socket socket = null;
       try {
           socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(result); // The objectDisposedException will come here... thus, it is to be expected!
           //Do something as you see it needs on client acceptance such as listing
           clientSockets.Add(socket); //may be needed later
           socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
           serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null); //to receive another client
       } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...        
           //Do something here
           Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
6. Define your `receiveCallback`, that is, when you receive something from your client. This part could be quite tricky because of failures! But basically, what you need for now is simply `EndReceive` and again, **very important**, to repeat the `BeginReceive` from the same client such that you can receive its next message!

   ```
   const int MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT = 10;
   static int receiveAttempt = 0; //this is not fool proof, obviously, since actually you must have multiple of this for multiple clients, but for the sake of simplicity I put this
   private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
       Socket socket = null;
       try {
           socket = (Socket)result.AsyncState; //this is to get the sender
           if (socket.Connected) { //simple checking
               int received = socket.EndReceive(result);
               if (received > 0) {
                   byte[] data = new byte[received]; //the data is in the byte[] format, not string!
                   Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length); //There are several way to do this according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c in general, System.Buffer.memcpyimpl is the fastest
                   //DO SOMETHING ON THE DATA IN byte[] data!! Yihaa!!
                   Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); //Here I just print it, but you need to do something else
                   receiveAttempt = 0; //reset receive attempt
                   socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
               } else if (receiveAttempt < MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT) { //fail but not exceeding max attempt, repeats
                   ++receiveAttempt; //increase receive attempt;
                   socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
               } else { //completely fails!
                   Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails!"); //don't repeat beginReceive
                   receiveAttempt = 0; //reset this for the next connection
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...
           Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails with exception! " + e.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
7. And suppose you want to reply your sender after you receive the message, simply do this in the `if (received > 0)` part:

   ```
   if (received > 0) {
       byte[] data = new byte[received]; //the data is in the byte[] format, not string!
       //DO SOMETHING ON THE DATA int byte[]!! Yihaa!!
       Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); //Here I just print it, but you need to do something else                     

       //Message retrieval part
       //Suppose you only want to declare that you receive data from a client to that client
       string msg = "I receive your message on: " + DateTime.Now;
       socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)); //Note that you actually send data in byte[]
       Console.WriteLine("I sent this message to the client: " + msg);

       receiveAttempt = 0; //reset receive attempt
       socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
   }
   ```
8. And after putting a little more things in your main routine, you are done(!) - **IF** you do not ask for sending to client as `byte[]`
9. And now, if you want to send something to **all** your clients as `byte[]` you simply need to list all your client (see step 4-5). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) and convert the `result` `string` above (remember to type it in hex `string` format as required) to `byte[]` then send it to all the clients using your client socket list (here is where it is needed!):

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
       Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
       serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
       serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
       serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);      

       //normally, there isn't anything else needed here
       string result = "";
       do {
           result = Console.ReadLine();
           if (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit") {
               byte[] bytes = null;
               //you can use `result` and change it to `bytes` by any mechanism which you want
               //the mechanism which suits you is probably the hex string to byte[]
               //this is the reason why you may want to list the client sockets
               foreach(Socket socket in clientSockets)
                   socket.Send(bytes); //send everything to all clients as bytes
           }
       } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
   }
   ```

And here, you are more or less done with your server. Next is your client

---

**Client:**

1. Similarly, put the `Socket` class in the class context rather than method context and initialize it as soon as you start your program

   ```
   const int PORT_NO = 2201;
   const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
   static Socket clientSocket; //put here
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       //Similarly, start defining your client socket as soon as you start. 
       clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

       //your other main routines
   }
   ```
2. Then start to connect by `ASync` `BeginConnect`. I would normally go further by `LoopConnect` just for failure handling like this.

   ```
   static void loopConnect(int noOfRetry, int attemptPeriodInSeconds) {
       int attempts = 0;
       while (!clientSocket.Connected && attempts < noOfRetry) {
           try {
               ++attempts;
               IAsyncResult result = clientSocket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP), PORT_NO, endConnect, null);
               result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attemptPeriodInSeconds));
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(attemptPeriodInSeconds * 1000);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
           }
       }
       if (!clientSocket.Connected) {
           Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt is unsuccessful!");
           return;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Similar concept to what you do to the server `BeginAccept` you need to define `endConnectCallback` for the `ASync` `BeginConnect` you use. But here, **unlike server** which needs to re-calling `BeginAccept`, once you are connected, you do not need to do any new `BeginConnect` since you only need to be connected **once**.
4. You may want to declare `buffer` etc. Then, after you connect, don't forget the next `ASync` `BeginReceive` to handle the message retrieval part (similar with the server)

   ```
   private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
   private static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //buffer size is limited to BUFFER_SIZE per message
   private static void endConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
       try {
           clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
           if (clientSocket.Connected) {
               clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), clientSocket);
           } else {
               Console.WriteLine("End of connection attempt, fail to connect...");
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Console.WriteLine("End-connection attempt is unsuccessful! " + e.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
5. Naturally, you need to define your `receiveCallback`, just like what you did for the server. And yes, it is as you have guessed, it is almost identical to what you did for the server!
6. You can do anything you want with your data. Note that the data you receive is actually in `byte[]`, not `string`. So you can do anything with it. But **for example's sake**, I will just use `string` to display.

   ```
   const int MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT = 10;
   static int receiveAttempt = 0;
   private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = null;
       try {
           socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)result.AsyncState;
           if (socket.Connected) {
               int received = socket.EndReceive(result);
               if (received > 0) {
                   receiveAttempt = 0;
                   byte[] data = new byte[received];
                   Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length); //copy the data from your buffer
                   //DO ANYTHING THAT YOU WANT WITH data, IT IS THE RECEIVED PACKET!
                   //Notice that your data is not string! It is actually byte[]
                   //For now I will just print it out
                   Console.WriteLine("Server: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                   socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
               } else if (receiveAttempt < MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT) { //not exceeding the max attempt, try again
                   ++receiveAttempt;
                   socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
               } else { //completely fails!
                   Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback is failed!");
                   receiveAttempt = 0;
                   clientSocket.Close();
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...
           Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback is failed! " + e.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
7. And at the very very last... Yes, again, as you have already guessed, you just need to do something on your main routine - suppose you want to use it to send data. Because you use `Console` but you want it to send things as `byte[]`, you need to do the conversion (see the explanation in server 9.). And afterwards you are completely done!!

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       //Similarly, start defining your client socket as soon as you start. 
       clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       loopConnect(3, 3); //for failure handling
       string result = "";
       do {
           result = Console.ReadLine(); //you need to change this part
           if (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit") {
               byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result); //Again, note that your data is actually of byte[], not string
               //do something on bytes by using the reference such that you can type in HEX STRING but sending thing in bytes
               clientSocket.Send(bytes);
           }
       } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
   }
   ```

---

**Results:**

Here you go! I tested it by sending `string` for display, but I already put up what is needed when you want to change it to `byte[]`

[image]

[image]

---

**Code for your test:**

**Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpListenerConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        const int PORT_NO = 2201;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        static Socket serverSocket;
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
            serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);      
            string result = "";
            do {
                result = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
        }

        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //buffer size is limited to BUFFER_SIZE per message
        private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult result) { //if the buffer is old, then there might already be something there...
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(result); // The objectDisposedException will come here... thus, it is to be expected!
                //Do something as you see it needs on client acceptance
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null); //to receive another client
            } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...        
                //Do something here             
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        const int MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT = 10;
        static int receiveAttempt = 0; //this is not fool proof, obviously, since actually you must have multiple of this for multiple clients, but for the sake of simplicity I put this
        private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = (Socket)result.AsyncState; //this is to get the sender
                if (socket.Connected) { //simple checking
                    int received = socket.EndReceive(result);
                    if (received > 0) {
                        byte[] data = new byte[received]; //the data is in the byte[] format, not string!
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length); //There are several way to do this according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c in general, System.Buffer.memcpyimpl is the fastest
                        //DO SOMETHING ON THE DATA int byte[]!! Yihaa!!
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); //Here I just print it, but you need to do something else                     

                        //Message retrieval part
                        //Suppose you only want to declare that you receive data from a client to that client
                        string msg = "I receive your message on: " + DateTime.Now;                      
                        socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)); //Note that you actually send data in byte[]
                        Console.WriteLine("I sent this message to the client: " + msg);

                        receiveAttempt = 0; //reset receive attempt
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
                    } else if (receiveAttempt < MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT) { //fail but not exceeding max attempt, repeats
                        ++receiveAttempt; //increase receive attempt;
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket); //repeat beginReceive
                    } else { //completely fails!
                        Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails!"); //don't repeat beginReceive
                        receiveAttempt = 0; //reset this for the next connection
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...
                Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback fails with exception! " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpClientConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        const int PORT_NO = 2201;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        static Socket clientSocket; //put here
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //Similarly, start defining your client socket as soon as you start. 
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            loopConnect(3, 3); //for failure handling
            string result = "";
            do {
                result = Console.ReadLine(); //you need to change this part
                if (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit") {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result); //Again, note that your data is actually of byte[], not string
                    //do something on bytes by using the reference such that you can type in HEX STRING but sending thing in bytes
                    clientSocket.Send(bytes);
                }
            } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
        }

        static void loopConnect(int noOfRetry, int attemptPeriodInSeconds) {
            int attempts = 0;
            while (!clientSocket.Connected && attempts < noOfRetry) {
                try {
                    ++attempts;
                    IAsyncResult result = clientSocket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP), PORT_NO, endConnectCallback, null);
                    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attemptPeriodInSeconds));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(attemptPeriodInSeconds * 1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            if (!clientSocket.Connected) {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt is unsuccessful!");
                return;
            }
        }

        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //buffer size is limited to BUFFER_SIZE per message
        private static void endConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
            try {
                clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
                if (clientSocket.Connected) {
                    clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), clientSocket);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("End of connection attempt, fail to connect...");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("End-connection attempt is unsuccessful! " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        const int MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT = 10;
        static int receiveAttempt = 0;
        private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
            System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)result.AsyncState;
                if (socket.Connected) {
                    int received = socket.EndReceive(result);
                    if (received > 0) {
                        receiveAttempt = 0;
                        byte[] data = new byte[received];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, data.Length); //There are several way to do this according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c in general, System.Buffer.memcpyimpl is the fastest
                        //DO ANYTHING THAT YOU WANT WITH data, IT IS THE RECEIVED PACKET!
                        //Notice that your data is not string! It is actually byte[]
                        //For now I will just print it out
                        Console.WriteLine("Server: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
                    } else if (receiveAttempt < MAX_RECEIVE_ATTEMPT) { //not exceeding the max attempt, try again
                        ++receiveAttempt;
                        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
                    } else { //completely fails!
                        Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback is failed!");
                        receiveAttempt = 0;
                        clientSocket.Close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { // this exception will happen when "this" is be disposed...
                Console.WriteLine("receiveCallback is failed! " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Last Remarks (Edit)**

Since the code above is run using `Console Application` it must be run with `static main void` keyword. And thus client `Socket` defined above is of `static` type. This may prevent the client `Socket` to be defined multiple times as each time it is "defined", since it is of the same `class` named `Program`, it will refer to the same `Socket` (though this may not always the case, at least according to the OP's experiment: he can run multiple clients successfully in the same computer).

Nevertheless, to overcome this is not that hard. Simply port the client application to the platform which is non-initiated as `static` class (such as `WinForms`) and all the above code would still run as per normal. Alternatively, if it must be run using the `Console Applications`, and the problem occurs, simply copy the client application and re-define it using different `namespace` or different `class` name to avoid defining identical `Socket` due to identical `namespace` or `class`.

But the most important part on this problem solving is the use of `Async` and `Sync` wisely to solve the given issue.

---

Continuation of this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767502/send-a-flag-from-server-to-clients-using-c-sharp-mouse-events)

Comment: @JoseRamon Yes! I checked it for you. It is really because of the `static` class. When I create another copy project, exactly the same, but I changed the `namespace` to something else, it runs perfectly fine...

Comment: In the client side code, how can i just listen for the server? I tried to remove the do while which actually sends data. However I cant manage to print the data I just send from the server side.

Comment: In fact what I am trying is to find what I should add in the main function of server in order to send data to the client. In case of client a socket is created after that the loopConect and then the send which actually sends data to the server. What of them should I add in the server side main function? How does send works? It sends to all ports that listen data? Is it possible a client to listen and wait data? Should I add bind and listen to the client side code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100532/discussion-between-ian-and-jose-ramon).

Comment: Hey Ian sorry for that silly question I am not familiar at all with networks. How can I retrieve the clientSockets list from server site? The listen functionality is only for the sever side? In order to read data from clients I have to use receiveCallback?

Comment: Actually now my code is inside in onMouseRight and onMouseLeft click. With right click I calling StartServcer in a new thread and after that recording function and onRightClick I have to do something in order to stop the server and the recording.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you make your life easier and use SignalR?
Below you can see a simple example where the server and the clients are console apps

**Client (Run this .exe many times)**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

namespace SignalRClient
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
        const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:1234/signalr";
        private static HubConnection Connection { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

            HubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", (name, message) => Console.WriteLine(name + ":" + message));
            Connection.Start().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop client");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server (Run this .exe before you run the clients)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace SignalRServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
        const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:1234";
        private static IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
        private static HubConnection Connection { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
            Console.WriteLine("Server running at " + ServerURI);

            Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            HubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", (name, message) => Console.WriteLine(name + ":" + message));
            Connection.Start().Wait();

            string messageToSentToClients;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type someting to send to clients and press enter");
                messageToSentToClients = Console.ReadLine();
               HubProxy.Invoke("Send", "Server", messageToSentToClients);
           } while (messageToSentToClients != "exit");

       }
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message) { Clients.All.sendMessage(name, message); }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) { app.MapSignalR(); }
    }
}
```

In order for the above to work you need the following NuGet packages:

**Client:**
          Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
**Server**
          Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
          Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
          Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
          Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener

If you want the server/clients to be on different machines all you have to do is change the ServeURI properties in both projects:

```
//Clients
const string ServerURI = "http://SERVER_IP:PORT/signalr";
//Server
const string ServerURI = "http://SERVER_IP:PORT";
```

You can find another similar example in WinForms here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Comment: I tried to create the form from the beggining. It actually worked properly, however when I tried to add a library of mine I got problems: An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'FileHelpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Comment: What could be the conflict concerning the library I try to add?

Comment: Which library are you trying to add?Have you checked these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869239/error-when-using-filehelpers-on-iis-sometimes-s-policyexception-required-p       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483550/replacing-dll-to-a-newer-version      http://serverfault.com/questions/93342/error-when-using-filehelpers-on-iis-sometimes-policyexception-required-perm

Comment: In fact FileHelpers is the lib of mine. When I comment the bunch of signalR code is working fine. However when I add in startServer SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI); line I am receiving the exception. It seems that I cant load properly my lib due to the signalR references.

Comment: The problem is not in FileHelpers itself.It's one of its dependencies.Check its reference one by one and make sure SignalR depends on the same version

Comment: I like this answer because it uses a library intended for this kind of work.  Why maintain custom multi-cast code and deal with network issues etc - your core problem is keeping the clients in sync, not writing a network library.

Answer (score 2):

You can send data to a client, and it can be achieved similarly to how you do so client -> server (unless your sockets are receive only, if so switch them to send and receive). Sending a Boolean requires conversion to a byte, you can achieve this via the BitConverter class.

Comment: Can I do so for several clients?

Comment: Yes.  Each client should have a socket. If you store each client in a collection somewhere, whenever you need to send the same data to all clients (or only specific clients) you can iterate through this collection and send the required data.

Comment: Currently I am returing a string which is  content = "false<EOF>" how can I remove the EOF character in order to parse the string to boolean variable?

Answer (score 2):

On page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx see method `AcceptCallback` (it's called when client connects). There is line `Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);`.
This happens for each client when it connects, so keep these Socket instances to some list.
When you want to send data to clients, use `Send` method from that same example with each socket from list (or selectively if you want to send only to some clients).

```
private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}
```

Comment: I have to keep all Socket listeners  to a list? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: In general I was confused for the client and listener functionalities. Can I have a server which just send data and clients which listening from the server?

Comment: Not socket listeners but sockets (instances of class `Socket`). But, yes, you need them, they represent your clients so sending to a socket is sending to a client.
Difference between listener and client is that you have one listener which waits for connections from clients but you have many clients, each represented by Socket instance.