# How to load image, convert it to jpg format and resize it

Tags: c#, image

I need to load an image from the computer, then convert it to jpg/jpeg and resize it to 60x60 and then send it via sockets. I know how to send an image but I don't know how to do the image processing in c sharp (windows forms)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load an image:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(filename);
```

To resize:

[How to resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp)

```
var bitmap = ResizeImage(image, 60, 60);
```

To transform to jpeg:

```
bitmap.Save(filenameNew, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

To send via socket:

[How to send file through socket in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600012/how-to-send-file-through-socket-in-c-sharp)

Adding:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```